# How to update sqlite listview item from adapter?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have `ListView` with `ImageButton`,

when I click the `ImageButton`, I want to update the field of the item.

here is my adapter bindView

```
@Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView txtArtist = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artist);
        TextView txtVolume = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.volume);
        TextView txtNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.number);

        ImageButton buttonHeart = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.heart);


        final int _id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("title"));
        String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("artist"));
        String volume = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("volume"));
        final String favorite = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("favorite"));
        String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("number"));

        // Populate fields with extracted properties
        txtTitle.setText(title);
        txtArtist.setText(artist);
        txtVolume.setText(volume);
        txtNumber.setText(number);

        if(favorite==null) {
            buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
        }else if(favorite.matches("1")){
            buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heartred);
        }

        buttonHeart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (arg0 != null) {
                    //UPDATE QUERY HERE
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

and here is my DbAdapter

```
package com.magicstarme.virtualsongbook;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


/**
 * Created by Joe on 7/7/2016.
 */
public class FragmentOne_DbAdapter {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
    public static final String KEY_VOLUME = "volume";
    public static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";
    public static final String KEY_FAVORITE = "favorite";
    public static final String KEY_NUMBER = "number";

    private static final String TAG = "FragmentOne_DbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Virtualsongbook";
    private static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "Player1";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
                    KEY_TITLE + "," +
                    KEY_ARTIST + "," +
                    KEY_VOLUME + "," +
                    KEY_TYPE + "," +
                    KEY_FAVORITE + "," +
                    KEY_NUMBER + ")";

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SQLITE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public FragmentOne_DbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public FragmentOne_DbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        if (mDbHelper != null) {
            mDbHelper.close();
        }
    }

    public long createPlayer1(String title,
                              String artist, String volume,
                              String type, String number) {

        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        initialValues.put(KEY_ARTIST, artist);
        initialValues.put(KEY_VOLUME, volume);
        initialValues.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
        initialValues.put(KEY_NUMBER, number);

        return mDb.insert(SQLITE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    public boolean deleteAllPlayer1() {

        int doneDelete = 0;
        doneDelete = mDb.delete(SQLITE_TABLE, null , null);
        Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(doneDelete));
        return doneDelete > 0;

    }

    public Cursor fetchPlayer1ByTitle(String titleText) throws SQLException {
        Log.w(TAG, titleText);
        Cursor mCursor = null;
        if (titleText == null  ||  titleText.length () == 0)  {
            mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                            KEY_TITLE, KEY_ARTIST, KEY_VOLUME, KEY_TYPE, KEY_FAVORITE, KEY_NUMBER},
                    null, null, null, null, null);

        }
        else {
            mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                            KEY_TITLE, KEY_ARTIST, KEY_VOLUME, KEY_TYPE, KEY_FAVORITE, KEY_NUMBER},
                    KEY_TITLE + " like '%" + titleText + "%'", null,
                    null, null, null, null);
        }
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

    public Cursor fetchAllPlayer1() {

        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                        KEY_TITLE, KEY_ARTIST, KEY_VOLUME, KEY_TYPE, KEY_FAVORITE, KEY_NUMBER},
                null, null, null, null, null);

        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public void insertPlayer1Songlist() {

        createPlayer1("Song Title 1", "Artist 1", "Vol 1","","12341");
        createPlayer1("Song Title 2", "Artist 2", "Vol 2","","12342");
        createPlayer1("Song Title 3", "Artist 3", "Vol 2","","12343");
        createPlayer1("Song Title 4", "Artist 4", "Vol 3","","12344");
        createPlayer1("Song Title 5", "Artist 5", "Vol 3","","12345");
        createPlayer1("Song Title 6", "Artist 6", "Vol 4","","12346");
        createPlayer1("Joe Song Title 7", "Artist 7", "Vol 4","","12347");
        createPlayer1("Song Title 8", "Artist 8", "Vol 1","","12348");
        createPlayer1("Song Title 9", "Artist 9", "Vol 1","","12349");
        createPlayer1("Song Title 1", "Artist 1", "Vol 1","","12341");
        createPlayer1("Song Title 2", "Artist 2", "Vol 2","","12342");
        createPlayer1("Song Title 3", "Artist 3", "Vol 2","","12343");
        createPlayer1("Song Title 4", "Artist 4", "Vol 3","","12344");
        createPlayer1("Song Title 5", "Artist 5", "Vol 3","","12345");
        createPlayer1("Song Title 6", "Artist 6", "Vol 4","","12346");
        createPlayer1("Song Title 7", "Artist 7", "Vol 4","","12347");
        createPlayer1("Song Title 8", "Artist 8", "Vol 1","","12348");
        createPlayer1("Song Title 9", "Artist 9", "Vol 1","","12349");
        createPlayer1("Joehamir Balabadan", "Artist 1", "Vol 1","","12341");
        createPlayer1("Song Title 2", "Artist 2", "Vol 2","","12342");
        createPlayer1("Song Title 3", "Artist 3", "Vol 2","","12343");
        createPlayer1("Song Title 4", "Artist 4", "Vol 3","","12344");
        createPlayer1("Song Title 5", "Artist 5", "Vol 3","","12345");
        createPlayer1("Song Title 6", "Artist 6", "Vol 4","","12346");
        createPlayer1("Song Title 7", "Artist 7", "Vol 4","","12347");
        createPlayer1("Song Title 8", "Artist 8", "Vol 1","","12348");
        createPlayer1("Song Title Joe 9", "Artist 9", "Vol 1","","12349");

    }
}
```

when I click `ImageButton`, I want to update favorite field from null to 1
then when favorite field is 1, I want to update is to null.

also I want to change imageResource when I click `ImageButton`..

from heart to hearthred and vise versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1> add this method in FragmentOne_DbAdapter

```
public int updateItemFavorite(int rowId, String favorite) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_FAVORITE, favorite);
    return mDb.update(SQLITE_TABLE, values, KEY_ROWID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(rowId) });
}
```

2> replace this code

```
if(favorite==null) {
        buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
    }else if(favorite.matches("1")){
        buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heartred);
    }
```

with

```
 if(favorite.matches("0")) {
        buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
    }else if(favorite.matches("1")){
        buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heartred);
    }
```

3> call updateItemFavorite image button click

```
buttonHeart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (arg0 != null) {
                FragmentOne_DbAdapter database=new FragmentOne_DbAdapter(context);

  if(favorite.matches("0")) {
        database.updateItemFavorite(_id,"1");
    }else if(favorite.matches("1")){
        database.updateItemFavorite(_id,"0");
    }
```

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//here adapter is my adapter class object

```
            }
        }
    });
```

i hope it useful to you

Comment: im getting this error ava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference

Comment: @joehamirbalabadan.com please use update answer now and it useful then tick right anwer

Comment: still getting this error.. java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at com.magicstarme.virtualsongbook.FragmentOne_DbAdapter.updateItemFavorite(FragmentOne_DbAdapter.java:143)

Comment: @joehamirbalabadan.com public int updateItemFavorite(int rowId, String favorite) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_FAVORITE, favorite);
    return mDb.update(SQLITE_TABLE, values, KEY_ROWID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(rowId) });
} use this

Comment: @joehamirbalabadan.com who are you call get item list from database in your code

Comment: @joehamirbalabadan.com use this in button click
FragmentOne_DbAdapter database=new FragmentOne_DbAdapter(context);
 database.open();
   if(favorite.matches("0")) {
            database.updateItemFavorite(_id,"1");
        }else if(favorite.matches("1")){
            database.updateItemFavorite(_id,"0");
        }

Comment: im getting error in this part.. if(favorite.matches("0")) { because in my insert i did not add value..
do i need to add 0 in my public void insertPlayer1Songlist() { 

createPlayer1("Song Title 1", "Artist 1", "Vol 1","","12341");

Comment: @joehamirbalabadan.com are you check in database favorte status update then after call adapter notify method on button click

Comment: how to refresh listview after clicking the heart button.. and also how to change heart button to red when i click? to notify the he click button.. thanks..

Comment: the update is working now but when i go to other fragment everything is going back to zero favorite..